# DataMapper fetching last record using .last throws no method error if using .any? in view

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, datamapper, instance-variables

Apologies for the long wined title, in my app I am trying to retrive e the last record from the database that matches the params I have passed to it.

```
@goals = Weight.last(:is_goal=>true,:user_id=>@user.id)
```

In my views I want to run a conditional that checks if there are any present and if it has it will display a div.

```
<% if @goals.any? %>
    <% @goals.each do |goal| %>
        <p><%= goal.amount %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But for some reason this throws a no method error `NoMethodError at /
undefined method 'any?'`. If I change the `.last` to `.all` it works

```
@goals = Weight.all(:is_goal=>true,:user_id=>@user.id)
```

Is there any reason behind this or have I found a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `.last` method returns an object, `.all` method returns an array of objects.
And `.any?` is an array method. You can't call `.any?` on an object, it will tell you that there is no method unless you have created one.

Comment: Ah thats brilliant thanks for that, so is there an equivalent of `.any?` for just an object?

Comment: You can try using `nil?`. As if there is no object, then it is set to nil. Keep in mind that it is not the same thing, it is just a different approach.